# VBA/MSACCESS/SQL query greater than or equal to

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

When I click a button in Excel, I have the query below that retrieves data from an Access DB.
It pulls data based on a date in a particular cell. This works fine.
However, the query is not able to retrieve based on the "greater than or equal to" condition.
It only pulls dates "equal to" what's in that cell reference.

```
Dim N As Date
N = Sheets("sheet1").Range("h3")
rs.Open "SELECT SID, Requestor, Comments, Updated_Date, Updated_By FROM CL WHERE datevalue(Updated_Date) >= '" & N & "'", cn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datevalue(Updated_Date)` returns a Date/Time value.  So compare it to a Date/Time value instead of a string.  Use `#` characters to delimit the Date/Time value.

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT SID, Requestor, Comments, Updated_Date, Updated_By " & _
    "FROM CL WHERE datevalue(Updated_Date) >= " & Format(N, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
rs.Open strSelect, cn
```

Comment: thank you mate!! this works like a charm. much appreciated for the quick revert :)